# APACHE2 cannot find newly installed version of PHP

Tags: php, apache2

I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 which comes with PHP 7.0. After the upgrade my local test site stopped being consistent with my off site test site [which still uses PHP 5.6].

To see what would happen, I uninstalled PHP 7.0 and installed PHP 5.6 on my local machine. But now PHP pages will not display. Even the phpinfo.php page shows a blank screen. But non PHP pages work fine.

How can I get APACHE2 to find PHP 5.6?

Comment: Check apache logs, is display errors enabled in the php.ini?  If Apache couldn't find PHP, it'd likely either show a 500 error or just display the PHP code rather than rendered output, not a blank page.

Comment: There is nothing like 500 errors in the Apache logs.  I will try to find the php.ini for php 5.6 and let you know.

Comment: /etc/php/5.6 has two sub directories. They are cli and embed. there is no apache2 sub directory. The embed sub directory has a php.ini file. I have turned the display errors to On in the embed copy. Since nothing changed I assume this is the wrong copy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with getting APACHE2 to find PHP 5.6.
I had failed to load libapache2-mod-php5.6. When I corrected
that the PHP pages loaded fine but the original problem
that caused me to revert to PHP 5.6 is still present.

I am going to close this question and open a new question
to address the original problem.